# pyenv command not found when running with sudo

Tags: python, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

04 under WSL.
I have binary of pyenv in my PATH even with sudo's PATH, but i cannot run it with sudo for some reason.

```
test@pc:~$ which pyenv
/home/test/.pyenv/bin/pyenv
test@pc:~$ sudo which pyenv
test@pc:~$ sudo echo $PATH | perl -p -e 's/:/\n/g' | grep pyenv
/home/test/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims
/home/test/.pyenv/shims
/home/test/.pyenv/bin
```

I tried to

```
sudo -i 
sudo -E
```

with pyenv and it doesnt works. Without sudo it works fine but i cannot install python because of permissions.
What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, `sudo` locates programs using its own `secure_path`, defined in the `/etc/sudoers/` file:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
```

Also note that when you do `sudo echo $PATH`, the `$PATH` variable is expanded by the user's shell before being passed to sudo. To see root's path using sudo, you would need to do something like `sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'`

Comment: Is there any option to pass my path to execute concrete command once without editing secure_path? 
```sudo -i -E``` doesnt work

Comment: @АлександрКуликов you could try using `env` - see for example [How to make `sudo` preserve $PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path)